# How to change text size in a specific div and then back to what it was in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is for an article on a web page, I want to allow users to make the article text larger or smaller (it will be nice if it can also reset back to the original bootstrap font size without hard coding the size)

I'm going to gave a minus and plus input buttons

**What is a good way to do it?**

**CLEARIFICATION:** I'm more interested in how to do it correctly with bootstrap in mind, it sets the font size to a specific size (how do I get it back to what it was after I changed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that might work for you. It first saves the original font size to the variable `fsStart` and declares a second variable `fs` with initially the same value and will save the current font size whenever you change it. The rest is pretty clear I think. This can be optimized of course, but I think you get the idea.

```js
var fsStart = parseInt($('.text').css('font-size'), 10);
var fs = parseInt($('.text').css('font-size'), 10);

console.log( 'fsStart: '+fsStart);

$('.minus').on('click', function() {
  fs -= 2;
  $('.text').css('font-size', fs + 'px');
  console.log(fs);
});
$('.plus').on('click', function() {
  fs += 2;
  $('.text').css('font-size', fs + 'px');
  console.log(fs);
});
$('.reset').on('click', function() {
  $('.text').css('font-size', fsStart + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
  <p>... sit amet ...</p>
  <p class="btns">
    <button class="minus"> - </button>
    <button class="reset"> o </button>
    <button class="plus"> + </button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes for each size and swap them on button click. The CSS for the two styles would be:

```
.text-large {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.text-small {
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

The buttons would be:

```
<button onclick="changeTextSize(false)">-</button>
<button onclick="changeTextSize(true)">+</button>
```

With this javascript:

```
function changeTextSize(toLarge) {
    var articleText = document.getElementById('article-text'); //Or whatever the id is
    if (toLarge) {
        articleText.className = articleText.className.replace('text-small', 'text-large');
    } else {
        articleText.className = articleText.className.replace('text-large', 'text-small');
    }
}
```

Haven't tested due to the lack of information in your answer meaning I don't know what your current code looks like.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could make three buttons for it. The first one is to make the text smaller from the original, the second for larges and the last button for the original view.

On each buttun you should make some php code which will do the changes.